# A Huge Thank You

Tags: thank, social-sound-design

I know this isn't really allowed and I'm breaking some rules here but i felt the need to thank everyone on this forum for all the knowledge, skills, tips and Yoda level wisdom i have gained since i joined last year. I especially want to thank the high level members including Jay Jennings, Utopia, Stavrosound and many others.. Your dedication to this forum blows my mind and you are extremely appreciated.

I just finished my first ever proper project working on a 6 minute animation for the Animation Workshop. The film is being played internationally at animation festivals and may even make it to CANNES! It's not paid as it's part of my degree but as a portfolio item and a networking opportunity it's priceless.

I couldn't of made it through it without this forum. Once again, thank you to everyone. I feel privileged to be part of the online community and i look forward to a healthy, creative career.

Thanks

Danny

Comment: This is actually very much allowed! Just [on our meta](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/) rather than on the main site. Is all! (Mods have the means to migrate it there. And anyone can flag it for mod attention for them to do just that.) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I wholeheartedly agree that this community is the beep!